# Como posso retornar para uma PartialView, deixando os dados carregados?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Possuo um sistema MVC, onde o usuário pode efetuar uma consulta dos cadastros. Para que isso ocorra, possuo uma View com os filtros e uma `PartialView` que é atualizada dentro da View, exibindo os resultados.

Na frente de cada cadastro exibido, existe uma opção para ver os detalhes do mesmo, onde redireciona o usuário para outra View.

O problema é que quando o usuário está na View de detalhes, ele pode clicar em "voltar", onde deveria retornar para a página de consulta, com os resultados da busca efetuada. Porém, por se tratar de uma `PartialView` onde os resultados são consultados eu tenho que retornar para ela. Mas isto causa um erro de JavaScript Não Definido, pois está sendo carregada uma `Partial` dentro de uma View que não foi recarregada.

O que posso fazer com isso?

Answer (score 2):

Como ao clicar em Detalhes o usuário é redirecionado para outra View, `uma alternativa é você passar os valores informados no(s) filtro(s) da consulta quando  o usuário clicar na opção de ver os detalhes do cadastro.`

Exemplo de um link Detalhes para passar os valores dos filtros na *View* que exibe o resultado da consulta:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Detalhe", "Detalhes", "SeuController", new 
{
    id = model.Id, 
    filtro1 = model.filtro1, 
    filtro2 = model.filtro2
})
```

Recebendo esses valores informados no(s) filtro(s) da consulta quando o usuário clicar em Detalhes, você poderá recarregar a tela anterior (contendo os resultados da consulta) quando o usuário clicar em "voltar" sua View de detalhes.

Exemplo no *Controller* de como receber valores dos filtros:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Detalhes(int id, string filtro1, int filtro2)
{
    var model = new DetalhesViewModel(id, filtro1, filtro2); 
    // Carrega o model/sua partial com os dados dos filtros informados
    ...
}
```

Agora, na sua *View* de Detalhes você tem os valores dos filtros e pode passá-los como parâmetro no seu link "Voltar" para remontar sua *View* de resultado da consulta:

Exemplo *View*: Passando os valores dos filtros no link Voltar para remontar a tela de consulta

```
@Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Consulta", "SeuController", new 
{
    filtro1 = model.filtro1, 
    filtro2 = model.filtro2
})
```

Exemplo *Controller* da consulta recebendo valores dos filtros:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Consulta(string filtro1, int filtro2)
{
    // Carrega o model aproveitando os filtros
    var model = new ConsultaViewModel(filtro1, filtro2); 
    return View(model);
}
```